# Navbar/header animated change on scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

It's difficult to explain, but I can't find a snippet like that anywhere ..also not really knowing for what term I have to search for. I would like to create, with CSS and jQuery, a header/navbar animation when I scroll the website. But not like in CSS animations depending on a specific duration but depending on the scroll itself. Basically exactly like this website http://www.vice.com/de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out your link and that looked like "parallax scrolling". Here is a plugin: http://pixelcog.com/parallax.js/

Comment: Thanks. I think this gets me a lot further. Maybe it just looks like it's just a single animation that is connected to the exact scroll speed rather than a fixed duration.

Comment: Yup2. The concept is to listen to `$(window).scroll()` function and move the targetted object abit slower or faster based on position top/bottom achieving the parallax scolling effect